# Swift Snapshot for version 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I'm new to iOS development, so thank you in advance for the help. I'm trying to build an application that was built in XCode 9.3 and Swift 4.1. When I install the packages using Carthage, it throws this error:

> "Skipped installing CryptoSwift.framework binary due to the error:
>       "Incompatible Swift version - framework was built with 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1) and the local version is 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)."

The reason for the error (very clear...) is because I'm trying to build the project using XCode 10.2 and Swift version 5.0.1. So in order to fix it, you need to go to the swifts snapshots and download the version I need and install it.

However, when I go to [the swifts snapshots](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots) I see the one for 4.1 but the links seem to be broken(?). It redirects me to the apple Xcode documentation.

Does anyone know where and how can I install the swift version I need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, try giving this a go(if not already):

> When using a newly released version of Xcode you'll have to build
>   libraries from source (by passing `--no-use-binaries` to `carthage
>   update`) until a new version of framework comes out which has pre-built
>   binaries for that Xcode version.

The above is an extract from: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6134 and it might help...